# How to open Entity records list page with specific view in Unified Interface App in MS Dynamics CRM 365 v9.0?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I want to open Entity records list page with specific view on button click in Unified User Interface app in MS Dynamics CRM 365 v9.0. For example, `Contacts` list page and `Active Contacts` view.

Following URL works find in Web

```
window.open(serverUrl + "/main.aspx?etn=contact&pagetype=entitylist&viewid={"61A3C426-36CC-43EF-8549-E6A525F2FC08"}&viewtype=1039&navbar=off&cmdbar=true");
```

I have tried with this URL too but it doesn't work in App

```
window.open(serverUrl + "/main.aspx?appid={yourAppId}?etn=contact&pagetype=entitylist&viewid={"61A3C426-36CC-43EF-8549-E6A525F2FC08"}&viewtype=1039&navbar=off&cmdbar=true");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Below Url structure:

```
http://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etn=contact&pagetype=entitylist&viewid={00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001004}&viewtype=1039&navbar=off&cmdbar=false
```

"viewtype" values are:
1039: For system View.
4230: For Personal View

[For more info please see this page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg328483(v=crm.8))

Comment: Thanks but I want a method(i.e. window.open(url)) to open entity list page. The URL you have suggested is correct but it works with browser only, it is not working in Unified User Interface App(MS Dynamics 365).